# Retrieving entities from a one to many relationship (Odata)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, odata, one-to-many

Summarizing, I have two main tables: **Company** and **Employees**, with a one-to-many relationship between them: employees belongs to a company.

The Company entity has a property called Employees, which allows to get the employees who belongs to the specific Company.

If I type in the browser this URL, it works and I get an employees list:

```
http://domain.com/DynamicsNAV80/OData/Company('whatever')/Employees
```

Now, I want to retrieve the employees using a Linq query, how can I do it?

I have tried this:

```
var dataServiceQuery = (DataServiceQuery<Company>)from comp in _context.Company.Expand(comp => comp.WhseEmployee)
                                                  where comp.Name == "whatever"
                                                  select comp.WhseEmployee;
```

But this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could do with this query:

```
    var dataServiceQuery = (DataServiceQuery<WhseEmployee>)_context.Company.Where(c => c.Name == companyName)
                                                                           .SelectMany(c => c.WhseEmployee);
```

Answer (score 0):

What does that query return, an error or just not the data your looking for? Im not sure if the syntax for querying Odata is different but this is how i would do it any other time.

```
              var dataServiceQuery = from comp in _context.Company.Expand("WhseEmployees")
                                     where comp.Name == "whatever"
                                     select comp;
```

Comment: That query returns an exception ("The method Select is not supported").

I only want to get the employees of a company, I would need the **equivalent linq query to this OData URL** : `http://domain.com/DynamicsNAV80/OData/Company('whatever')/Employees`

Comment: Check out the updated query and let me know what that does for you.

Comment: Maybe you don't trust me, but Employee entity doesn't has CompanyId property, and Company doesn't has EmployeeId property.

Also, it's a one to many relationship, not one to one.


I don't know how the relationship is built. but the URL is working for me with `/Company('whatever')/Employees`

Comment: Its not that i dont trust you, without a view of your tables im stabbing in the dark. They would have to have a related field or perhaps an additional relational table to have a one to many relationship. What i assumed from your info is that each (1) Company can have (many)Employees. If the Employees table doesnt contain a field that relates to the company, then look for a relational table like CompanyEmployees

Comment: @ Rick here is an snapshot of some information about the tables and database.

http://s4.postimg.org/6mzzypar1/SHOT.png

Here I said that the name of one the tables was Employee, but is WsheEmployee.

Instead of `/Company('whatever')/Employees` the correct URL is `/Company('whatever')/WsheEmployee`

I modified some names in order to explain it better.

Comment: @Fran_gg7 , lets try that again. This link may help as well.

Comment: I get this error...

`<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><m:error xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\"><m:code /><m:message xml:lang=\"en-US\">Not Implemented</m:message></m:error>`

Comment: I think this service does not support $expand or $select ..... is there some alternative to this?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of OData are you using?

If it is V4. You can try following code.

```
var employees = _context.Company.ByKey("whatever").WhseEmployee;
```

Please refer to [Client Delayed Query](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/07/09/client-delayed-query.aspx)

If it is V3. You need to query the company first, and then use LoadProperty to send request to /Company('whatever')/WsheEmployee.

```
var company = _context.Company.Where(c=>c.Name="whatever").First();
dsc.LoadProperty(company, "WsheEmployee");
```